# Passing arrays through an interface as pointers and then populating another array with them

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

A bit of a weird one for me so I was hoping you peeps can help me out a little. I basically have an objective of **populating an array which will consist of 16 bytes**. Furthermore, I even have the structure of this array which I will have to create
[image]

The problem I am having is that apart from the first two basic values from this list, everything else is populated by passing them as arguments in a function which I do not have access to. It is not something made by my part of the project, and thus the only information I have about the function is its interface which is basically `ReturnType GetValues(uint8* index, uint8* ID, uint8* buffer)`.

Another issue is how I can basically place in this 16 element array, another array in it of itself. Take note that this is supposed to be scalable, so I can't just manually put all 10 elements of the buffer array into the bigger array, because in the future I might have to do the same for a 100-byte array and so on.

A basic implementation for what I have is something like this

```
uint8 index[2];
uint8 ID[2];
uint8 buffer[10];

GetValues(index, ID, buffer);

uint8 FinalArray[] = {0x01, 0x10, buffer, index, ID};
```

Of course there are issues with all of this, first of all the fact that buffer, ID and index are passed in the GetValues function where they will be treated as pointers, and then I just casually throw them inside the FinalArray. Unfortunately I am new to C, and as such even though I know basic algorithms, the pointers and memory management aspect of the language still eludes me at times. I appreciate any help you guys can offer. Thanks!

Comment: Please ask only 1 question per submission.  I am not sure, what your two questions are.  Arrays in C are of uniform types, so it's really a line protocol.  As you talk about byte order it's strange they don't tell you which order index and ID uses.

Comment: That is something I struggle with. I thought that maybe both index and ID are actually uint16 because in the picture it says they occupy 2 bytes. I mean for buffer they wrote 'buffer[0], buffer[1] etc.'. But for index and ID, it's just their names, both on 2 bytes.

But then again, GetValues definitely takes only uint8* values, so I considered them as arrays.

Comment: For your `GetValues()` function is your `index` and `ID` in, out or inout parameters?

Comment: @AllanWind, I guess my question is: I call the GetValues function so that buffer, ID and index don't stay empty. How can I afterwards populate the FinalArray? Because I know my definition of it earlier does not really make sense, basically declaring it and putting inside another array 'buffer' as an element.

Comment: Please edit your question (and delete your comment) with clarification.

Comment: @AllanWind they are just in parameters.  The function just returns 1 or 0 based on if the copying mechanism worked or not. So the values for 'index', 'ID' and 'buffer" are modified within the GetValues function, without them being given back through a "return".

Comment: If the function modifies those arguments they are either out or inout.  If it doesn't then they ought to be const (and I understand it's not your fault).

Comment: To answer your question, btw, memcpy is how you can copy things from buffer to FinalArray, or you can assign individual fields.  For index, for example, index[0] and index[1] (or reverse depending on byte order)

Comment: @AllanWind Yes, maybe I need to ask for more clarification about that. Even the part with index and ID which I initially thought were uint16, but then put them as arrays of uint8 because they cover 2 bytes each. Anyway, thanks for your assistance, maybe once I get stuff more clearly, I will post again the questions in a new thread with more details. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass pointers at given offsets from your array directly to your function.

```
uint8 packet[16] = { 0x01, 0x10 };
                                                 
GetValues(packet + 12, packet + 14, packet + 2);
```

Assuming and `uint8` is a *character type*, and the endianness of `ID` and `index` values are correct (otherwise you need functionality similar to [`htons`/`ntohs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/htons)).

<sup>(*Maybe some macros to replace these magic numbers.*)</sup>

Comment: I modified my initial post, I think now both index an ID are actually uint16 variables. This is why in the table, each element from the buffer array was put individually on each byte, while index and ID were actually placed each on 2 cells. I thus concluded that in fact they are single elements which occupy 2 bytes each.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanted to ask you, are you saying this is the only way to actually populate the 'packet' array in your example? I can't call the GetValues function and only afterwards create the 'packet' array with the values modified by the GetValue function?

Comment: You can certainly use `GetValues` to populate whatever you want, and then copy those values *to* wherever you want, by whichever means is appropriate (e.g., assignment, `memcpy`, etc.), but you cannot initialize an array in C by *expanding* another array to grab all its elements. i.e., `uint8 FinalArray[] = {0x01, 0x10, buffer, index, ID};` attempts to initialize an array with two `int` values, and three `uint8 *` values (converted to `uint8`).

Comment: So can I for example do something like
FinalArray[0] = 0x01;
FinalArray[1] = 0x10;
memcpy(&FinalArray[2], index, sizeof(index));

Does this seem OK for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes (other than the offset being `&FinalArray[12]`), but since we are assuming `GetValues` already does that exact byte-wise copy, its rather redundant. You already have the memory (if `uint8 FinalArray[16]`, then `FinalArray + 12` is effectively a `uint8 [4]` which you just want to use the first half of in your comment's example). The expected endianness of `index` and `ID` is the only unclear issue I see here.